# Explain this: 40' long strip of bark removed from white pine

Tags: new-england

Seen today (5/5/19) in an area north of Boston.
[image: bark stripped from white pine]

Comment: Welcome!! I live west of Boston! I agree with @blacksmith37 that it's a lightning strike. Those areas can burn inside the tree without knocking it over. Did you see evidence of fire? Do you go there often? I'd be curious to see if it lives through the next few months. Some can hold up to the strike but many die shortly. If you check on it in a while would you mind reporting its health? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Lightening strike. I have seen the exact same on a Loblolly Pine then lightening lifted a few feet of soil toward the buried sewer line.